# Google maps Pricing

Tags: google-maps, dictionary

I'm creating an app that takes pictures I took around the country and opens them via clickable markers on the map.  They are GPS linked and this information will be stored on my own server.  Let's say 25000 people downloaded the app and used it (although I don't think I would...)  Would this be considered a Dynamic Map or a Native Dynamic Map?

Pricing on the Native dynamic Map is completely free, (I think) whereas if it is dynamic it is limited to a $200 credit and 25000 page loads.  But I'm not sure if this is Native Dynamic or Dynamic.

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Google's pricing, not coding.

Comment: And where should I post it to be on topic?

Comment: Native Dynamic Map refers to Google Maps Android SDK and Google Maps iOS SDK, while Dynamic Map refers to Google Maps JavaScript API. If you use SDK for mobile (Android or iOS) it's free of charge.